# exec() cordova command via php on Windows

Tags: php, windows, cordova, xampp, exec

I use xampp on my Windows system and i try to run command `cordova --version` via php exec() function. I tried run cordova directly from path `C:/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova --version` but it doesn't work.

With this two cases exec returns empty output, what's wrong?

Comment: so, it doesnt work directly with C:/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova --version ?

Comment: nope, output is still empty

Comment: does anything else work when you do php exec() ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem happen because you are running `exec` as XAMP user.

Each user has his own **Environment Variables** so you have to define them.

```
$envVars = "PATH=...";
putenv($envVars);
```

As a trick you can open CMD with your user and run this command:

```
echo %PATH%
```

This will return your current user "PATH" Environment Variable, so you can use the returned string as the "`$envVar`" value.
Don't forget to

- Escape backslash "\" to "\\"
- Don't copy all your Environment Variables, just select which ones you will need for cordova (npm).